# On openshift, is there any apache at front of my tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, openshift

when https is used on openshift, is my tomcat behind an apache server?
I mean does my clients connect to my tomcat directly or they connect to the apache server, and then the apache server connect to my tomcat through AJP connector?

If apache is the man in the middle, then I will not get my clients' IP address directly, but with x-forward http header. And I lose the control over certificate verification and trust management. At present, I am using mochahost's server. https does not get to my tomcat, but intercepted by an apache. I hate this.

Previously, I used another hosting service, even 2 apache servers are at front of my tomcat server. Even more ridiculous that 2 apache servers and my tomcat servers are on the same machine. This kind of configuration can only show the system architecture does not have the right ability to manage the whole thing.

By the way, I am talking about the Bronze/Silver plan. I guess Openshift is not different though I have not tried it yet. Anyone has a clear answer to my question?

https is against the man in the middle, but with tomcat server, in this world, there is no service that you can avoid the man in the middle. It is not because technology does not allow, but the people in charge does not really understand the thing, so not able and not willing to provide the right service.

I want to ask: if you use tomcat server, is there any hosting service provider who does not act as a man in the middle? No. There is none on this world at present (May 2014)!

jack

Comment: This is because tomcat has no way to start on port 80 without running as root - which is not going to be allowed by anybody

Comment: To@TheSteve0, seems to me what you said is not right, reasons: #1. Suppose tomcat can run on 80/443 not as root, will they configure in this way? No! Unless they can provide private IP. Otherwise your tomcat running on 80/443 will take over the whole IP. #2. suppose private IP is provided,then linux permission mechanism should be used, so authbind & other tools can be used to bind 80/443 (non-root!). #3. Suppose with private IP, and because they do not understand the permission mechanism, 80/443 are still not allowed, IP table can be used to boost performance, rather than go through apache.

Comment: To @TheSteve0, overall because the persons on that position were trained only with apache, so they do not know linux permission mechanism, do not know IP table. At redhat, this should not happen since I would guess they have some people who knows the permission mechanism very well. Why they do not use it? I guess different departments! There is no synergy yet. I think I understand the architecture pretty well, but I am not able to get that position.

Comment: On a linux system the only user that can bind to port 80 is root. You can use IPtables to reroute but then to modify iptables you also need to be tables. This is often why people front Tomcat with Apache. Apache has better mechanism to bind to port 80 but then run as Apache. It will then proxy the calls to Tomcat

Comment: Thank you for being responsive, but I am wondering whether you have checked what authbind/privbind & setcap etc are.You need to be root to modify iptables is different from the app run as root. The way you put it made me to think you are one of those guys and your education with linux & security is questionable. my personal opinion might be wrong.@TheSteve0

Comment: This is a RHEL system and from most of the research I have done your solutions seem to only run on Debian. I do agree my experience is older (as in mid2000s) but most serious sysadmins I know run Tomcat on a non-priveliged port and then proxy with Apache or use IPtables.

Comment: You mean authbind(1998)/privbind(2006) only works with debian? or capabilities(2003) works only with debian? Are you sure? Now seems to me, your ability/capability is questionable (previously, I only doubt your education on linux and security)(Of course, I might be wrong). The "most serious sysadmins" you mentioned, they just follow suit, they are not interested in improving performance and better configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is an apache reverse proxy located in front of your tomcat instance that does ssl termination.  The Apache instance is at the node level, then tomcat runs on your gear.

Comment: So you mean my clients can not reach my tomcat server through https directly. What if I got a static/private IP? The IP is only for me, still they will put apache at front my tomcat server, am I right? As I know mochahost does so, and they do not want to change. By the way, you are a user of openshift, or you are working for openshift? I mean your credibility of your answer.

Comment: We do not offer static ip addresses on OpenShift Online, all requests are proxied through apache or node.js